# if paypal plan has “inactive” status?

Tags: paypal

Working with Update Plan API 
http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/billing/UpdatePlan.html
I did not find if plan has “inactive” state and which key have I to use for it?
I made :

```
$value = new PayPalModel('{
   "state":"INACTIVE"
 }');
```

But got error :

> Requested state change is invalid.

1) How valid?

2) If in my developer's account there is a page where I can see all my plans and work with them in my developer's account ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code taken from:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/BankAccount.php

The BankAccount API extends PayPalModel and uses $state on the following line: 392

Here is the array:

```
 /**
 * State of this funding instrument.
 * Valid Values: ["ACTIVE", "INACTIVE", "DELETED"]
 *
 * @param string $state
 * 
 * @return $this
 */

public function setState($state)
{
    $this->state = $state;
    return $this;
}
```

From this [PayPal Rest API - Update Billing Plan Return URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631597/paypal-rest-api-update-billing-plan-return-url?rq=1) answer it might appear that you already have agreements attached to your plan so therefore you cannot make it INACTIVE.